# Linker option for multiple definition of function

Tags: linker

Is there any Linker option, which enforces error for multiple definition of a function.
I am using ARM GCC mingw.

I am facing problem where if I am using Guard in header file(say A.h) like this
   `#ifndef H_H_`
   `#define H_H_`

and declare function definition inside it

Linker is not giving error for Multiple definitions of  that function in different .C files which includes above A.h file

Comment: pragma guards prevent you from including a single header multiple times in the same cpp file ("Translation Unit").  pragma guards do nothing to prevent a header from being included in multiple cpp files.  Including a header with declarations multiple times is not an error, and _ought_ to be done.  As long as they're just declarations and not definitions.  If a function is defined multiple times, GCC will give a linker error.  It sounds to me like you have no problems here.

Comment: The linker *already* does what you ask for without any options. It is exceedingly likely that your description of what's happening is incorrect, and you jumped to wrong conclusion. Show the source for `A.h`, the compile and link lines you use, and you are likely to get your misunderstanding corrected.

Comment: Please don't ask almost the same question over and over again, but provide an MCVE. The part with the header guards is not reproducable with the information given.